# Diagonalization of a matrix with a defecit of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

If a  square matrix $A$ of order $n$ has $r$ linearly independent eigenvectors, then it is possible to write $S^{+} A S=\Lambda$ where $S$ is the "eigenvector matrix of r linearly independent columns$^{\prime \prime}$ and $\Lambda$ the "eigenvalue matrix of the corresponding linearly independent eigenvectors  " and $S^{+}$ is the left inverse of $S$ .

Is this a valid case of diagonalization? Does this diagonalization have any use?

Comment: Have a look on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition#Jordan_decomposition)

Comment: Thank you, but I failed to find a relevant passage. If you don't mind could you be precise?